# IP NAT pool range

Tags: networking, cisco, nat

When is it necessary to setup a pool of more than one address?

So if I have this ip pool range:

*ip nat pool demo 72.32.11.65 72.32.11.66 netmask 255.255.255.252*

What's the difference if I just have one address?

*ip nat pool demo 72.32.11.65 72.32.11.65 netmask 255.255.255.252*

Comment: can't you overload the nat pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using overload (PAT), it only makes a difference if you make very many (tens of thousands) of simultaneous outbound connections.  If you're *not* using overload, you'll need one outside global IP address per inside local IP address that will be translated through that pool.